# WPF C# Stride it too low for CopyPixels method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to convert a BitmapSource into a BitmapImage because of the Interface I am using. If I display the BitmapSource to an Image view, it works. but when I try and convert the BitmapSource into a BitmapImage, I get this error: "The parameter value cannot be less than '3686400'.\r\nParameter name: buffer" string

My PixelFormat  is Bgr24

Here is my code :

```
   void GetFrame(BitmapSource image)
    {
        try
        {

            BitmapSourceImageChanged?.Invoke(image);   

            BitmapImage tempImage = new BitmapImage();

            //tempImage  = image as BitmapImage;

        //    Frame = tempImage; var temp = image.Format;


        int imagePixelHeight = image.PixelHeight;
        int imagePixelWidth = image.PixelWidth;

             byte[] pixels = new byte[imagePixelHeight * imagePixelWidth];

             int stride = (imagePixelWidth * image.Format.BitsPerPixel +7) / 8;

             image.CopyPixels(pixels,stride,0);

             Frame = BitmapImageFromArray(pixels, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);
             if (Frame == null)
            {
                int stop = 0;
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception  err)
        {
          Error =  err.Message;
        }
    }

    BitmapImage BitmapImageFromArray(byte[] transfer, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

        try
        {
            using (
                // Convert byte array to BitmapImage()
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(transfer))
            {
                image.BeginInit();

                image.DecodePixelWidth = imageWidth;
                image.DecodePixelHeight = imageHeight;
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

                image.EndInit();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }

        return image;
    }
```

My code throws the exception at the CopyPixels method.

Is my stride equation not correct?

Comment: "*convert a BitmapSource into a BitmapImage because of the Interface I am using*" - that sounds like it would not make sense. An interface that explicitly expects a BitmapImage is badly designed. It should instead expect a BitmapSource.

Comment: Besides that, you could could at first attempt to cast the BitmapSource because it may already be a BitmapImage, like `var bitmapImage = image as BitmapImage;` and check if that returns null or not.

Comment: Clemens, if you look at the code I posted you will see I did try that. I commented out because it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stride calculation is ok, but not the calculation of the buffer size.

The buffer size is the product of the number of scan lines and the bytes per scan line, i.e. the stride:

```
int stride = (imagePixelWidth * image.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

byte[] pixels = new byte[imagePixelHeight * stride]; // here
```

However, your code will still not work, since you can not *decode* a BitmapImage from a raw pixel buffer. Decoding means to read an encoded bitmap frame, for example a JPG or PNG.

In order to decode a BitmapImage, you would have to create an encoded frame first:

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapSourceToBitmapImage(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    var bitmapImage = bitmapSource as BitmapImage;

    if (bitmapImage == null)
    {
        bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder(); // or some other encoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

---

That said, there should actually never be a need to have a method like the above at all. All properties that are relevant for a bitmap in WPF are declared in the BitmapSource class. The additional properties in BitmapImage are only used during creation, but have no relevance afterwards.

Comment: Oh so that is why you said, the Interface is  badly designed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should not be like that. What is that interface, or its implementation, doing with specifically a BitmapImage, that could not as well be done with a BitmapSource?

Comment: Clemens you were right, I changed the interface to a  BitmapSource   and the code works for both cameras without me having to convert any Images.  I was only using BitmapImage in the Interface, because the 1st camera has sample C# code that use it  and I just did what they were going. but I change Frame to a BitmapSource  and it works . Thanks again !

Comment: How do I mark Clemens other comment as a answer too ?